# Filtering jquery datatable based on a column value

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatables

I'm using JQuery Datatable for my Table Listings. 
Here is my table structure

```
UserName        |        Education
---------------------------------------------
Philip          |        Graduate
John            |        Post Graduate
Alex            |        Graduate
Emily           |        Phd
Elan            |        Post Graduate
George          |        Phd
....................................
....................................
Tom             |        Graduate
------------------------------------------------------
```

But I've a requirement of putting a dropdown next to filter textbox in which there will be 3 options. When we choose first option say graduate, that will list only graduates, same way if we choose phd, that will list phd users only. Hope the question is clear.

Also am sharing my datatable call

```
$('#tbl_users').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row'<'col-md-6'i><'col-md-3'f>>t<'space20'><'row'<'col-md-3'l><'col-md-9'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "oLanguage": {

        "sInfo": "<span class='label label-info'>_START_</span> to <span class='label label-info'>_END_</span> of <span class='label label-info'>_TOTAL_ users</span>",
        "sEmptyTable": "<div class='alert alert-info'>No users in this Account</div>",
        "sSearch": "<span class='input-icon'><i class='clip-search-2 '></i>_INPUT_</span>",
        "sLengthMenu": '<div class="form-group"><select class="form-control">' +
        '<option value="6">6</option>' +
        '<option value="10">10</option>' +
        '<option value="20">20</option>' +
        '<option value="50">50</option>' +
        '<option value="-1">All</option>' +
        '</select> /Page</div>'
    },
    "iDisplayLength": 6,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bSort": false,
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0]}]
});
```

Hope the situation is clear...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [fnFilter](https://datatables.net/api#fnFilter) function for this.

Say your new selectlist had an id of MySelectList, you would create a listener for the change event and call `fnFilter`, passing the selected value.

```
$("#MySelectList").on('change', function () {
    oTable.fnFilter(this.value, 0);
});
```

To make this work, you would need to initialise your datatable like this:

```
var oTable = $('#tbl_users').dataTable({
...
```

Depending on how you're populating the data, you'll need to cater for the custom filter value in the codebehind if that's how you're doing it, the parameter would be passed in `Request["sSearch_0"]`

Comment: can we pass multiple values to `fnFilter()` function? `$('#vendorTable').dataTable().fnFilter($("#filterVendorName").val());
$('#vendorTable').dataTable().fnFilter($("#filterStatus").val());
$('#vendorTable').dataTable().fnFilter($("#filterVendorId").val());` but not worked, I tried this also `$('#vendorTable').dataTable().fnFilter($("#filterVendorId").val(), $("#filterStatus").val(),$("#filterVendorName").val())`